# Android Expandable Listview customization on child view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i want to implement expandable list view with multiple child layouts.
all works fine but problem om,child view..child not appear on appropriate position....
here is my code...PLZ HELP ME..

i think problem on getchildview().i not able to hold child id of each parent...

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    Button btn;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        Object childPosititon;
        if(convertView == null )
        {
        if ( getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition)!=3) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list, null);
        }
        else if( getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition)==3)
        {

            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.vibrate, null);

        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

    }
        return convertView;
    }

    private List<String> get(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listgroup, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        //btn=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        lblListHeader.setTag(""+groupPosition);
        OnTouchListener item = null;
        lblListHeader.setOnTouchListener(item);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    public int getViewTypeCount() 
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int groupposition,int childposition) {

        if (getChildId(groupposition, childposition)==3) 
            return 0;

        //Not free
        else 
            return 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`BaseExpandableListAdapter` doesn't have `getViewTypeCount()` and getItemViewType(). in order to have different children view types you have to override the following methods instead.

```
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
if (getChildId(groupposition, childposition)==3) 
        return 0;

    //Not free
    else 
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do both child layouts have a textview with the same id?. Also, why not directly to use childPosition instead of getChildId()?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by add and remove the header view under the parent group layout. 
If you group layout is a `LinearLayout` that have `orientation="vertical"` like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/group_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

I add a references to the `ExpandableListView` in my constructor for my `ExpandListAdapter` so I can check if the group is expanded

```
 private ExpandableListView list;

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups, ExpandableListView list) {
        this.list = list;   
    }
```

and then in top of the method `getGroupView` check if it is expandet and add or if it is not remove

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Group group = getGroup(groupPosition);

    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_list_row, null);
    final View childheader = inf.inflate(R.layout.child_list_header, null);

    LinearLayout groupLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.group_layout_id);

    if(list.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
        groupLayout.addView(childheader, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }else{
        groupLayout.removeView(childheader);
    }
```