# How to create Expandable listview with dynamic multiple child view in android

Tags: android, list, view, customization, expandable

I want to create Expandable list view with dynamic child view. Child View has different view. I follow many url but nothing fits on my requirement. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I find a library for you [Expandable List View](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView)

With this library you can define diferents layour for parent and childs.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Thanks for reply .Its very helpful but I need different child view like for example : Parent list contain 3 child view, first child view have text view, second have image view and third contain button.

Comment: You can do it with diferent item view types in your child adapter. You have three types of view for childs and in your adapter you choose the correct view depending of type.

Comment: I tried this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830915/android-expandable-listview-customization-on-child-view   here there are child position issue comes as mentioned but the suggested solution not work. Can you help.